# Is it possible to change one of an element in a list, even though it appears in the list multiple times?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make a simple text based almost horror game and I've gotten the whole inventory list down as `inventory = ["-","-","-","-"]`. Right at the beginning of the game, you are offered help. If you agree, you get a skeleton key. If not, you don't. I've coded the skeleton key to be `inventory[0] = "Skeleton Key (3/3)"` so it replaces the '-' in index 0. But if the player doesn't choose help, then when they pick up the next item, it will automatically go into index 1, if I do it the same way.
Is there an easier way to replace first iteration of the same thing in a list?

I tried to use a for loop, but it just changed all of the '-' into 'key'.

Comment: Why not start with empty list and append each item when found?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Probably you forgot to stop the loop after the item was replaced once.

Comment: Throughout the game, you can use the skeleton key three times. I wouldn't know how to change the name of an element if it can be used multiple times. (The skeleton key starts in the player's inventory as |Skeleton Key (3/3)| so the player knows how many more times they can use it. How would I change the element if I don't know what index it is?)

Comment: Instead of thinking of the "number of uses" as part of the name, have a separate value that indicates the number of remaining uses - you can then have dictionaries instead of strings in your list, for example with `{"name": "Skeleton Key", "uses": 3, "used": 0}` - and then format that entry as you want when printing it out. When the user uses the skeleton key, increase the `used` count, and your UI will show the new value automagically. You might also want a `"type": "SKELETON_KEY"` or similar as well, so you can easily check if the user actually has a skeleton key, regardless of the name

Comment: Not to solve your problem specifically, but you might want to look into different data structures for a game, such as e.g. dictionaries or general objects (as in OOP).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index function to find the position of the first "-" and use that index for the new item:

```
if "-" in inventory:
    inventory[inventory.index("-")] = "Skeleton Key (3/3)"   
else:
    print("no more room in inventory")
```